# y-axis not aligned by their values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have list data like following:
The first element is PM level and the second one is the dates.

```
[
['83', '89', '88', '86', '85', '83', '86', '85', '86', '89', '88', '89', 
 '90', '88', '85', '85', '84', '80', '85', '-', '103', '107', '104', '106']

['2017-12-29 15:00', '2017-12-29 16:00', '2017-12-29 17:00', '2017-12-29 18:00', 
 '2017-12-29 19:00', '2017-12-29 20:00', '2017-12-29 21:00', '2017-12-29 22:00',
 '2017-12-29 23:00', '2017-12-29 24:00', '2017-12-30 01:00', '2017-12-30 02:00', 
 '2017-12-30 03:00', '2017-12-30 04:00', '2017-12-30 05:00', '2017-12-30 06:00',
 '2017-12-30 07:00', '2017-12-30 08:00', '2017-12-30 09:00', '2017-12-30 11:00',
 '2017-12-30 12:00', '2017-12-30 13:00', '2017-12-30 14:00', '2017-12-30 15:00']]
```

This is the part of the relevant snippets of my program.

```
@app.route('/pm25')
def pm25_graph():
    data_list = Display.data_retrieval()
    pm10, pm25, dates = data_list
    fig = Figure(figsize=(12, 5), dpi=100)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, title="PM 25 Level")
    ax.plot_date(dates, pm25, '-')
    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    png_output = BytesIO()
    canvas.print_png(png_output)
    response = make_response(png_output.getvalue())
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
    return response
```

When I ran the program, I got:

[image: the graph that the y-axis values are not arranged by their values]

Please someone help me how to fix this problem. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your y-values are strings and are therefore sorted lexicographically, i.e `107` is less than `80` due to the leading `1`. You need to convert them into numbers:

```
new_pm25 = []
for x in pm25:
    try:
        new_pm25.append(float(x))
    except ValueError:
        new_pm25.append(float('nan'))
```

Now you can plot:

```
ax.plot_date(dates, new_pm25, '-')
```

Result:

[image]